# Using "this" within a method

Tags: java, methods, this

Can I use `this` in the method, or is it wrong?

Fields:

```
private int level;
private String name;
```

Methods

```
public void check(String Name, int newlevel)
{
       if (this.level < newlevel )
       {
           this.level = newslevel;
           this.Name = Name;

           System.out.println("." Name+" you are in the right level);
       }
       else
       {
           System.out.println("Sorry your are not on the right level" );
       }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes. You can do this. It's often used in setters:

```
public void setX(int x) {
   this.x = x;
}
```

In the above, if you omit the `this`, you're simply setting the parameter `x` to itself - not what you want! For this reason, the keyword `final` is often used:

```
public void setX(final int x) {
   this.x = x;
}
```

In the above, if you omit the `this`, then the compiler will complain that you're setting `x` to itself.

Answer (score 2):

> can I use this in the method

`this` is mostly used in methods, just as you are using it. It refers to the the object on which the method is called, this implies that it **cannot be used in static methods**

Answer (score 0):

yes, its absolutely fine .`this` is usually used to refer to the `current object`. we use `this` to diffrentiate between the `instance variables` and `local variables`.

```
 private name;
 public void m1(String name){
 this.name=name;
 }
```

Comment: is it okay to leave the parameter as newLevel OR do i have to change it to level

Comment: you can leave it as newLevel, if you change it to level then you should definitely use this.level(instance variable)= level(local variable)

Comment: you are welcome, please accept the most appropriate answer if you are happy with one :)